# Why do we need non-trivial fibrations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, quantum-information, geometry, topology

I am currently reading [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0108137) paper. I understand how the [Bloch sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) $S^2$ is presented as a geometric representation of the observables of a two-state system:

$$ \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle \quad \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C} \quad \longrightarrow \{(\langle\sigma_x\rangle ,\langle\sigma_y\rangle ,\langle\sigma_z\rangle )\} = S^2 \subset\mathbb{R}^3$$

I also understand how $S^3$ is presented as a geometric representation of the same two-state system:

$$ \alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle \quad \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C} \quad \longrightarrow {(Re(\alpha),Im(\alpha),Re(\beta),Im(\beta))}=S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$$

I see that the Bloch sphere representation loses the information about a global phase, but I do not understand why we *need* a non-trivial (Hopf) fibration of $S^3$ to preserve this phase information. Why can't we simply assign to every point of the Bloch sphere a phase $e^{i\phi}$? Why does the two-state system demand a non-trivial fibration (and why specifically the Hopf fibration)?

**PS (and a possible partial answer)**: Since the Bloch sphere contains all of the observable information about the system, the $S^3$ representation has to be "decomposable" into pieces such that one of the pieces is the Bloch sphere. Since $S^3\not = S^2\otimes S^1$, we need a more complicated decomposition, e.g. the Hopf fibration. But this still leaves the question: is there no other decomposition of $S^3$ that will do the trick?

Comment: You seem to assume that we want our space to locally look like $S^2\times S^1$ - why? Perhaps there is another way to 'twist and glue the spaces' to get $S^3$ from $S^2$? I agree that the fibration cannot be globally a trivial product, but why do we limit ourselves to Hopf?

Comment: ^That would be much appreciated. The math S.E. answer seems a little hard to parse.

Here is another very related question: two-qubit systems are often represented as the Hopf fibration $S^3\hookrightarrow S^7\rightarrow S^4$ (and analogously for three qubits) - are these representations unique? Reasoning as in my PS above I see that we need a base of $S^4$, that our full space is $S^7$, and that a trivial tensor product won't do - is the Hopf fibration a unique nontrivial fibration of $S^7$ with base $S^3$?

Comment: I deleted my comments and made them into an answer as promise.

Answer (score 5):

> Why can't we simply assign to every point of the Bloch sphere a phase $e^{i\phi}$?

This is the idea of a section of a [fibre bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle). You are considering in this case a base space $S^{2}$ with fibre $S^{1}$. Locally the fibre bundle looks like $S^{2}×S^{1}$.
 However you want to consider a fibration such that the global space is not the trivial product but $S^{3}$. The Hopf fibration allows you to twist and glue the spaces to obtain the identification you want.

Is this the only fibration that gives you $S^{3}$? The answer is yes, but to see it requires some knowledge in algebraic topology and characteristic classes. Basically [circle bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_bundle) are classified up to bundle isomorphism by the first [Chern class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class). The next step is to see that the Hopf fibration belongs to the class of $1\in H^{2}(\cal{S^{2},\mathbb{Z}})$. You can do that by constructing long fibre sequences as done [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hopf+fibration). Finally you have to prove that any other circle bundle with total space $S^{3}$ belongs to this class. I asked that in mathstackexchnage and this was the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764429/is-the-hopf-fibration-the-only-fibration-with-total-space-s3).

Another answer can be formulated in terms of the [Hopf invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant) which is an homotopy invariant. A theorem by Frank Adams and subsequently by Michael Atiyah with methods of topological K-theory proved the only maps of Hopf invariant 1 are the sphere bundles in dimensions 2, 4 and 8. This settle the question if you are happy to consider the same as meaning the same up to homotopy equivalence. A proof of considering the same as the same up to homeomorphism for the base, fiber and total space can be found in this [paper.](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Price.pdf) (Corollary 3.9, Theorem 6.1) 
This also cover the other cases you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

The hopf-fibration is a projection from the 3-sphere to the 2-sphere. This is a dimensional reduction. The *"extra"* 4th-dimensional information from the 4d space of the quaternion is encoded in the lower 3d space via the global phase. The global phase is a natural hidden variable of the qubit in the *"lower"* 3d space - for more info see;

*Unit Quaternions and the Bloch Sphere:*
https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4999

The hopf-fibration
$$\mathbb{S}^3\mapsto^{\mathbb{S}^1}\mathbb{S}^2$$
is defined by
$$\hat{\mathcal{R}}\;=\;\hat{\Psi}\frac{\hat{\sigma}_i}{2}\hat{\Psi}^\dagger$$

$\bullet$  $\mathbb{S}^3$ The quaternion (spinor) $\hat{\Psi}(\theta,\phi,\omega)$ describes the 3-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

$\bullet$  $\mathbb{S}^2$ The bloch vector $\hat{\mathcal{R}}(\theta,\phi)$ describes the 2-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

$\bullet$  $\mathbb{S}^1$ The global phase $e^{i\frac{\omega}{2}}$ describes the 1-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The global phase is a natural hidden variable of the quaternion (spinor/qubit) when viewed in the Bloch sphere representation - $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the fiber bundle connecting the 3-sphere and 2-sphere. This non-trivial hopf-fibration is parameterized by the global phase, which is defined:

$$\omega\;=\;\int_0^tdt'\left[\frac{\mathcal{R}^j\mathcal{H}^j+\mathcal{R}^k\mathcal{H}^k}{(\mathcal{R}^j)^2+(\mathcal{R}^k)^2}\right]$$

where $\mathcal{R}^\bullet$ are the elements of the Bloch vector and  $\mathcal{H}^\bullet$ are the elements of the Hamiltonian - which satisfy the von neumann equation
$$\dot{\hat{\mathcal{R}}}\;=\;[\mathcal{\hat{H}},\hat{\mathcal{R}}]$$
expressed in the cayley basis.

The global phase tells you where you are *"globally"* on the 3-sphere. For example if we choose some closed path on the Bloch sphere and calculate that the global phase of one orbit is $\omega=2\pi$, then the $\mathbb{S}^1$ fibration
$$e^{i\frac{2\pi}{2}}=-1$$
The negative coefficient tells us that we have only traveled half of the total path on the 3-sphere. While it appears we have reached our starting point after one orbit, in actuality we require a second orbit of the path on the Bloch sphere to return to the initial point.

Interpreted physically this accounts for the intrinsic spin of the spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ fermions. The fermions require 2 orbits to return to their inital point - a $4\pi$ rotation. for more info see;

*The Hopf-Fibration and Hidden Variables in Quantum and Classical Mechanics:*
http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02569

(I authored the above article.)

Answer (score -3):

Mantras like “the Bloch sphere contains all of the observable information about the system” are junk. This implicitly refers to the concept of a (pure) quantum state, and confuses it with an important concept of *observable*, but quantum states are a tricky stuff and [the word “information” may become especially treacherous](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/110739/where-does-deleted-information-go).

Let us start from mathematics. Relevant formalisms are: Hilbert spaces, their projectivizations, and observables. Yes, when you get the ℂ<sup>2</sup> Hilbert space (for two states) and then restrict yourself to norm-1 state vectors, then you give a 3-sphere. Why vectors different only by a U(1) multiplication represent the same state? Because values of observables (2 × 2 complex matrices) on them and their probabilities do not depend on phase. So, it is convenient to consider the projectivization; eigenstates of (non-degenerate self-conjugated) operators become uniquely defined, without annoying U(1) freedom for each of them. Not this concrete Hopf fibration does matter; the projectivization on a Hilbert space, in general, does matter. There is no choice: all Hilbert space of the same dimension are isomorphic, and projectivization is unique. It happens that all such fibrations (except the case of one-state quantum system, ℂ projectivized to singleton) are non-trivial; just a mathematical fact. I emphasize: these are slightly different mathematical formalisms for states; each has both advantages and shortcomings. The usefulness of projectivizations does not permit you to ignore U(1) in *any calculation*. It means that if you consider a quantum system in isolation, then the U(1) action on its quantum states may be ignored in descriptions of its behaviour.

You *can* “simply assign to every point of the Bloch sphere a phase”, but it just **doesn’t make any sense**. You will not obtain the structure of a linear space, not to say such mapping to ℂ<sup>2</sup>\{0} may not be continuous. You lose invariance and symmetry of projective formalism without gaining linearity of the Hilbert spaces’ one.

I could also explain in details the C*-algebra of observables on a qubit and its relation the sphere/ball, but this thing isn’t asked.

Now physics. If you want to understand something about quantum states, then you might **forbid yourself to think that any qubit has some *definite* pure quantum state** (hint: consider an EPR pair). If one ever said you such thing, then s/he was a liar. Our world does not contain qubits in isolation; all quantum systems are *potentially* entangled.

Comment: I see, somebody has no arguments to use in discussion about ℂ², Riemann/Bloch sphere, and 2 × 2 matrices? Well, pressing “▼” is a determined outcome.