# Why can transform the $\rm SU(2)$ spin to $S^2$ space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-theory, representation-theory, spherical-harmonics, coherent-states

Spin lies in $\rm SU(2)$ space, i.e. $S^3$ space, but when we write the spin coherent state:
$$|\Omega(\theta, \phi)\rangle=e^{i S \chi} \sqrt{(2 S) !} \sum_{m} \frac{e^{i m \phi}\left(\cos \frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{S+m}\left(\sin \frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{S-m}}{\sqrt{(S+m) !} \sqrt{(S-m) !}}|S, m\rangle$$
where $\Omega$ is the unit vector in the $S^2$ space:
$$\boldsymbol{\Omega}(\theta,\phi)=\{\sin \theta \cos \phi,\sin \theta \sin \phi,\cos \theta\}.$$
Also, we need to choose appropriate gauge $\chi$, e.g. $\chi=\pm \phi$ to make spin coherent state $|\Omega(\theta, \phi)\rangle$ periodic:
$$|\Omega(\theta, \phi+2\pi)\rangle=|\Omega(\theta, \phi)\rangle.$$
As we know, one property for spin is "rotate back after $4\pi$" ($\rm SU(2)$ property), but why we now can change it to $S^2$ space (both unit vector $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ and $|\Omega\rangle)$ i.e. rotate back after $2\pi$.

**Note:** Someone says it can be understood as [Hopf map](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HopfMap.html):
$$\boldsymbol{n}=\left(\begin{array}{ll}u^{*} & v^{*}\end{array}\right) \boldsymbol{\sigma}\left(\begin{array}{l}\boldsymbol{u} \\ \boldsymbol{v}\end{array}\right)$$
which maps $S^3 \to S^2$, but I still cannot understand its picture since I think it must lose some information?

Comment: [Fibration (WP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration).

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109492/why-do-we-need-non-trivial-fibrations).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks so much for your comments! I think combining your link and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/204090/understanding-the-bloch-sphere may be more complete.

Comment: @CosmasZachos But I am not familiar with the mathematics about fibration, I still confused that does the physical effect of "loss of phase" related with the Berry phase term obtained in spin path integral?